# Pandas in python: Why is it printing "Empty DataFrame" and how do I stop it?

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get 3 strings from 3 columns in a HTML table but the output keeps looking like this:

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [o]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1]
Index: []

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('http://wiimmfi.de/stats/game/mprimeds', skiprows = [0], encoding = 'utf-8')

df[0].columns
ls_stat = df[0]["ls​_​stat"].to_string(index = False)
ol_stat = df[0]["ol​_​stat"].to_string(index = False)
status = df[0]["status"].to_string(index = False)

print(ls_stat)
print(ol_stat)
print(status)
```

It persists to print 'Empty DataFrame Columns:[] index:[]' for each string despite there being values in row 0 of the table. I just want the output to be:

0
o
1

Containing nothing but the values from the table.

How do I stop pandas from printing the rest? This is what the table on the website looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L909.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and this is what I got. You can print `df[0]` nicely formatted as such:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(df[0], headers = 'keys'))
```

and it will look like this. At the very least there are two rows.

```
    ('id4', 'AMHE')      ('pid', '600959457')  ('fc', '3871-4801-6097')    ('host', '—')    ('gid', '—')      ('ls\u200b_\u200bstat', '0')  ('ol\u200b_\u200bstat', 'og')      ('status', '2')  ('suspend', '—')      ('n', '1')  ('name1', 'りー')    ('name2', '—')
--  -----------------  ----------------------  --------------------------  ---------------  --------------  ------------------------------  -------------------------------  -----------------  ------------------  ------------  -------------------  ----------------
 0  AMHE                            601081334  5159-9715-6854              —                —                                            0  o                                                6  —                              1  ュoco×èno™           —
 1  AMHE                            601087019  0564-3566-1867              —                —                                            0  og                                               2  —                              1  atrueboss            —
```

we also note that the columns are a multi-index -- each label is a tuple, not a simple name. We can double-check by printing `df[0].columns` (which you already do in your code):

```
MultiIndex([(      'id4',           'AMHE'),
            (      'pid',      '600959457'),
            (       'fc', '3871-4801-6097'),
            (     'host',              '—'),
            (      'gid',              '—'),
            ('ls​_​stat',              '0'),
            ('ol​_​stat',             'og'),
            (   'status',              '2'),
            (  'suspend',              '—'),
            (        'n',              '1'),
            (    'name1',             'りー'),
            (    'name2',              '—')],
           )
```

so to get to the first column you want, we do (note the index `('ls​_​stat','0')` that we figured out above from `df[0].columns`)

```
print(df[0][('ls​_​stat','0')].to_string(index = False))
```

so we get

```
 0
 0
```

as expected.

For the `ol_stat` we use the same trick

```
print(df[0][('ol​_​stat','og')].to_string(index = False))
```

and we get

```
  o
 og
```

as expected. And so on.